# Format of tick values on axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a chart where I can choose what goes on the two axis. It can go from kilometers per week, where the max value is a bit more than 7 billions. To fatal accidents, where the max value is a bit more than 10.
When I call my axis, I use this :

```
.call(axeX.tickFormat(d3.format(".0s")))
```

If I don't, the number of kilometers per week are suuuuper long and it's a bit ugly. But now, the numbers on the axis are wrong, as you can see on this picture :

[image]

The working example is here : https://crashdavions.github.io/

What format should I use so that big numbers are in a suitable format (like 7G instead of 7 billions), but the small numbers remain in a "normal" format (like 10 and not 10.0000)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is useful [demo page](http://bl.ocks.org/zanarmstrong/05c1e95bf7aa16c4768e) when you can play with various format specifiers and choose to suit your needs. But no universal specifier. What numbers are considered as small? It is subjective. You can apply appropriate format specifier by a condition. For your case:

```
.call(axeX.tickFormat(function(number) {
    var specifier = number > 999 ? d3.format(".0s") : d3.format("");
    return specifier(number);
}))
```

This code returns `11` for 11, but `1k` for 1000.

Comment: Thanks for the demo page ! I tried your code but I get [this](https://i.imgur.com/wew7nwE.png). What I don't get is that if I put random stuff in `d3.format()` it doesn't work, so the browser knows `(".0s")` is a real format. But the output doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @Arnaud Stephan Oh, my bed. I updated the answer. You should pass the current number to specifier.